# Access denied accessing web part

Tags: web-part, permissions, visual-studio, email, custom-web-parts

We have created a custom web part that sends e-mail. A page is created, the web part is added on the page, and the page is published by an administrator.

The issue now is that all other users have problems opening this page, even people that have the permission to contribute and approve. The message we get is the standard:

> "Sorry, the site hasn't been shared with you".

Anybody else that have had this kind of issue with a custom web part ?
Apparently this has something with permissions to do, but it is weird. Any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions!

The page you have created does it inherit any permissions?
If not then you should create a page from someplace where you know that everybody has permissions.

Otherwise that page you made only has the Owners (Your administrator) on it.